# Rules regarding a portmanteau that includes an initialism

Tags: initialisms, portmanteau-words

Are there rules for creating a portmanteau using an initialism and part of a word?

Examples:

- ATM + empathy = ATMpathy
- SOS + espionage = SOSpionage

Are there existing examples of this?  Should they be hyphenated?  Is this unholy?

Comment: Neither of these examples seems likely in the real world. Is this a real problem?

Comment: I don't get what they are supposed to mean. To me, they look like random combinations of a final letter that is pronounced the same as the first syllable. Anyway, I dislike words like 'staycation'.

Comment: Yes this is unholy and should be criminalized.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is "ufology," from "UFO" + "-ology." Strictly speaking that's more a case of adding a suffix than creating a portmanteau. But in that case the initialism gets lowercased when incorporated into the word, so we have "ufology" instead of "UFOlogy."